# TypeError with `int` for `jsonify` from Flask

Tags: python, flask

When I `jsonify` a dictionary result that looks like

```
{'options': {'seriesName': 'Count', 'startYear': 2009, 'title': 'Title', 'startMonth': 9, 'startDay': 1, 'data': [39, 199, 1137, 1156, 1168, 1821, 1936, 214, 236, 260, 282, 305, 323, 344, 3565, 384, 411, 430, 4540, 473, 521, 548, 576, 6222, 6257, 6982, 7216, 2746, 78230, 8126, 85432, 943217, 1024323, 1113, 1155, 142196, 1243, 1271, 1290, 1327, 1365, 1407, 1451, 1537, 1642, 1742, 1811, 1862, 1936, 1978, 2012, 20655, 2093, 2156, 2203, 22289, 24319, 254424, 2614, 2682, 2755, 2811, 2862, 2949, 30262, 31615, 32301, 343309, 343299, 364236, 332721], 'yAxisLabel': 'Count', 'yMinValue': 0}}
```

I end up with

```
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: 39 is not JSON serializable
```

To my understanding `39` should be serializable correct?

This appears to be failing on the first `int` in the list. Is there a behavior of `jsonify` that I am no aware of?

Comment: Are you sure it is an actual integer, and not, say a `numpy.float64` object (which looks the same when `repr()` represented). Pandas produces such objects too. What does `type(object['options']['data'][0])` produce?

Comment: Can you tell us how you produced the `data` list at all? Then we can be of much better help avoiding this issue in the first place.

Comment: Wow, thank you Martijn. That was exactly the problem (<type 'numpy.int64'>). Spent much more time on this than I should have. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: TIL @MartijnPieters is a witch!

Answer (score 5):

You don't have an actual integer. You probably have a `numpy.float64` or similar object, which *looks* a lot like an integer when printed. Pandas dataframes produce these, for example, see their [*Gotchas* documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions).

You'll have to convert these to `int` or teach the Flask `JSONEncoder` how to handle these, explicitly.

For a numpy `ndarray` convert to a list using the [`.tolist()` method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) to get native Python types.